# Can I repost unanswered questions from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I have several questions on Stack Overflow which were never closed, but never received an answer. Would I be allowed to repost the same question here (as long as it's Magento related)?

If so, would the SO version have to be closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Treat Magento.SE and Stack Overflow as two separate sites.

Because, uh, they are.

If it's *your* question, and you honestly do want an answer to it, go ahead and ask it here. Heck, you can do that even if it already has an answer on SO and you simply want a better one.

What you want to *avoid* is "mechanical migration" - re-posting questions you don't need answers to here and then copying answers in from SO, just to pad the numbers. That doesn't allow anyone to demonstrate their Magento expertise, and creates an artificial sense of progress when nothing's actually happening.